# How can I set up a transparent proxy using squid and squidguard which has time-based acl based on MAC addresses?

Tags: mac-address, transparent-proxy, squid

I have a linux based server and I want to control access to internet based on MAC addresses of devices. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I've never tested it myself, but this can be done in `Squid` config file, but not with `Squidguard`.

You will have to enable this feature by compiling `Squid` with `--enable-arp-acl` configure option. I admit i am unsure if this option is embedded in some package repositories.

Then, you can configure ACLs, something like this :

```
acl mac1 arp ff:ff:ee:aa:00:00
acl mac2 arp 11:12:13:14:15:16
http_access allow mac1
http_access allow mac2
http_access deny all
```

However, be adviced that filtering on MAC Address will only work if your clients devices and your `Squid` box are on the same subnet.

[You can check this doc for further infos](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl#Can_I_set_up_ACL.27s_based_on_MAC_address_rather_than_IP.3F).

[Also, here some sample rules](http://tecadmin.net/configure-squid-proxy-server-mac-address-based-filtering/).

Good luck !